# Django use only some fields in ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have three classes

```
 Class Company(models.Model):
     name     = CharField( max_length = 26 , blank = True)
     #(...)

 class Person(models.Model):
     name     = CharField( max_length = 26 , blank = True)
     function = CharField( max_length = 50 , blank = True)
     company  = ForeignKey ( Company , related_name = 'persons' )
     # All the company table inside the data base is loaded in order to make the query,
     # This make a HUGE amount of data and takes too many time...
     # (...)
     def __unicode__(self):
          # caption uses both name and company__name fields but no other fields
          return self.name + '(' + self.company.name + ')'

 class Contact(models.Model):
      person  =  ForeignKey ( Person )
```

In order to optimise performances, I would like the latest person field to use

```
Person.objects.all().only('name', 'company__name')
```

as queryset.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use proxy models :

```
 class Person_short_manager(Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(self, Person_short_manager).get_query_set().only('name','company__name')

 class Person_short(Person):
    objects = Person_short_manager(Manager)
    class Meta:
         proxy = True
```

then replace

```
 person  =  ForeignKey ( Person )
```

by

```
 person  =  ForeignKey ( Person_short )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use values method, which return a subclass of QuerySet called ValuesQuerySet.

```
Person.objects.all().values('name', 'company__name')
```

For more information [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#values)

Comment: Yes, indeed, buit my interrogation is more about using those values INSIDE the query made to construct the select element, not obtaining them OUTSIDE the FOREIGN KEY field...

Comment: @MUYBelgium, you are talking about to use this fields on filter?

Comment: @MUYBelgium I don't see what you want to do neither.